# Send Arabic text as a parameter in python POST request

Tags: python, html, python-requests, http-post

I'm trying to login to a website using python POST request.

I've noticed that I need to send Arabic text as a parameter in this POST request.

for example: `txt="مرحبا"`

How may I send this? By encoding it? How can I encode it?

Comment: Have you tried UTF-16 or UTF-32?